# Is there way to invert only specific pixels with Pillow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am making a program where you can chose an image and a color and it will invert only the pixels that match that color. I've been surfing stackoverflow and reddit for solutions but so far no luck.

I tried to do something like this first:

```
img = Image.open('past.png')
pixels = img.load()
for i in goodpixels:
    ImageOps.invert(pixels[i])
```

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'mode'

No luck with that because ImageOps.invert only inverts full images. Next I tried to use ImageOps.polarize but realized that I couldn't use it because it takes greyscale thresholds not rgb values.

```
img = Image.open('past.png')
pixels = img.load()
for i in goodpixels:
    ImageOps.solarize(img, threshold=pixels[i])
```

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'tuple'

This is my issue, I don't know if this is even possible. If it takes too much work I will probably abandon the project anyways because I'm just keeping myself occupied, and this isn't for marks/job.

Some more code:

```
def checkpixels():
    img = Image.open('past.png')
    height, width = img.size
    img = img.convert('RGB')
    targetcolor = input('What color do you want to search for, you can use RGB format or common names like \'red\', \'black\', e.t.c. Leave this blank to invert all pixels. ')
    print('Processing image. This could take several minutes.')
    isrgb = re.match(r'\d+, \d+, \d+|\(\d+, \d+, \d+\)', targetcolor)
    if type(isrgb) == re.Match:
        targetcolor = targetcolor.strip('()')
        targetcolor = targetcolor.split(', ')
        targetcolor = tuple(map(int, targetcolor))
        print(str(targetcolor))
        for x in range(width):
            for y in range(height):
                color = img.getpixel((y-1, x-1))
                if color == targetcolor:
                    goodpixels.append((y-1, x-1))
    else:
        try:
            targetcolor = ImageColor.getcolor(targetcolor.lower(), 'RGB')
            print(targetcolor)
            for x in range(width):
                for y in range(height):
                    color = img.getpixel((y-1, x-1))
                    if color == targetcolor:
                        goodpixels.append((y-1, x-1))
        except:
            print('Not a valid color smh.')

    return goodpixels
goodpixels = []
goodpixels = checkpixels()
```

**Edit**: I figured it out! Thank you to Mark Setchell for his incredible brain! I ended up using numpy to convert the image and target color to arrays, making an inverted copy of the image, and using numpy.where() to decide whether or not to switch out the pixels. I also plan on making the target color a range so the chosen color doesn't have to be so specific. All in all my code looks like this:

```
goodpixels = []
targetcolor = inputcolor()
img = Image.open('past.png')
invertimage = img.copy().convert('RGB')
invertimage = ImageOps.invert(invertimage)
invertimage.save('invert.png')
pastarray = np.array(img)
targetcolorarray = np.array(targetcolor)
pixels = img.load()
inverse = np.array(invertimage)
result = np.where((pastarray==targetcolorarray).all(axis=-1)[...,None], inverse, pastarray)
Image.fromarray(result.astype(np.uint8)).save('result.png')
```

Of course, inputcolor() is a function offscreen which just decides if the input is a color name or rgb value. Also I used `import numpy as np` in this example.

A problem that I had was that original my .where method looked like this:

`result = np.where((pastarray==[0, 0, 0]).all(axis=-1)[...,None], inverse, pastarray)`

This brought up the error: `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'`
It turns out all I had to do was convert my color into an array!

Comment: It's only a couple of lines with Numpy which is what you should be using with images since it has many algorithms and is very fast. So convert your PIL Image to Numpy array make a copy of the whole thing and invert it all. Then use `np.where()` to choose, for each pixel location whether to use the original image or the inverted one.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks! I'll look into numpy.

Comment: It should look like this pretty much... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59322460/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell That was so helpful! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I'm not near a computer to help in more detail. If you work out how to do it, you can write it up as an answer for others to use and accept it as correct and bag the points. Good luck! Come back if you get stuck - questions are free

Comment: @MarkSetchell when I followed the advice in the linked answer I got the error:         AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'


`result = np.where((pastarray==[0, 0, 0]).all(axis=-1)[...,None], inverse, print('help'))`

Comment: Keep trying! If you have some new code, click `edit` under your question and add it in!

Comment: @MarkSetchell I figured it out, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Many libraries allow you to import an image into Python as a numpy array. `PIL` or `opencv2` are well documented libraries for working with images:

`pip install opencv2`

Example numpy.where() selection, meeting a set criteria, in this case inverting all pixel values below `THRESHOLD`:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# cut off thereshold
THRESHOLD = 230

pixel_data = cv2.imread('filename.png')
pixel_data = np.where(pixel_data < THRESHOLD, 1/pixel_data, pixel_data)

# display the edited image using matplotlib
plt.imshow(pixel_data)
```

The `numpy.where()` function applies a condition to your numpy array. More details available on the: [numpy official documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)