# Open CV: pasting one image over another changes its color

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am getting the colored part from one image and posting it on another, however when I paste it on another image, I see the color is getting changed and it is a bit transparent too. How can I make sure the color is not changing and its not transparent . Below is my code:

Note: Both soruce and target image are of same size.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("target_image.jpg")
im = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

c_shape_r = (446, 0, 34, 157)
c_shape_l = (0, 103, 33, 167)

# Reading the image using pillow
left_shape = Image.open("black_image.jpg"))
#cropping the shape from original source image
left_sh_im = left_shape.crop((c_shape_l[0],c_shape_l[1],
                                    c_shape_l[2]+c_shape_l[0] ,c_shape_l[3]+c_shape_l[1]))

# convert it to np array
left_shape = np.array(left_sh_im)

# Now I get everything from source image which is not black and paste it on the target image.

im[c_shape_l[1]: c_shape_l[1] + c_shape_l[3], 
          c_shape_l[0]: c_shape_l[0] + c_shape_l[2],
         ] = np.where(left_shape < [100, 100, 100], im[c_shape_l[1]: c_shape_l[1] + c_shape_l[3], 
         c_shape_l[0]: c_shape_l[0] + c_shape_l[2],
         ], left_shape)

# I do the similar for right side pathcing.

plt.imshow(im ,cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Blue patch:

[image]
[image]

Orange Patch:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I find your code somewhat difficult to read with the rather long repeated variable names, but suspect the error is in the `np.where()` statement which you hope is checking 3 values but isn't actually. I suspect you need an additional `.any()` or `.all()`. See example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59322460/2836621 Failing that, save your  intermediate images so you know what you have at each stage and then use your debugger.

Comment: Also, I have no idea where you get transparency from with JPEG input images. And I would generally recommend against mixing PIL, and OpenCV and matplotlib - it just confuses things (RGB vs GBR, palette vs non-palette, unsigned char vs float, different colourmaps,  automatic display scaling) and adds unnecessary dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Mark, let me try adding .all/.any, also the other approach I am thinking is to use contour to get patch mask and color that part in open cv on target image.

Comment: A simpler way might be to make the patches transparent where they are black and then just paste them on top.